# Xcode 6 Crashes when I attempt to create a new project

Tags: ios, xcode

This occurs after I hit next on the screen with the project identifier as well as project name.  The error I get is this

http://pastebin.com/CAwc4L0K

I apologize for the link but I was unaware of what area of the error message was important as I am unfamiliar with crash messages.

I have already fully restarted my computer as well as Xcode, opening previous projects works fine.

Comment: Did you file a bug report?

Comment: @Abizern The crash page said that the report would be send automatically to apple.